# iDRAC 5 on home network?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, vps, dell-poweredge, vsphere

So I bought a second hand [Dell Poweredge 1950 R3](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/poweredge-1950/pd) and I bought it with a [iDRAC 5 interface card](https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/how-to-use-dell-idrac-virtual-media/). I am going to use it for college this year and use it as a vSphere host as my college course requires a lot of different operating systems.

I am wondering with the iDRAC and vSphere is it possible to both port forward them on to when I am in college I can remote into the iDrac when I need the server on and then still be able to connect to my VPS’s on the server?

Comment: PS: Its a small world, say hi to Nicola for me, she'll be able to guess who this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dual embedded Broadcom® NetXtreme II™ 5708 Gigabit2 Ethernet NIC with fail-over andload balancing;
```

And

```
Standard Baseboard Management Controller with IMPI 2.0 support; optional DRAC5 for advanced capabilities
```

Haven't administered DELLs IPMI before but its often possible to associate webUI of an IPMI with 1x interface or its own physical port where applicable on some boards. Say on my personal server I have:

```
LAN1 .2.220
LAN2 .2.221
IMPI .2.222
```

This means my forwards to services on the OS go to .2.220 and I have all ports to use, but if I brows to .2.222:80 I get the IPMI.

iDRAC is configured through a DELL utility, I suggest you install that on the host OS and test it all out before configuring all your VMs. 2xNICs should be enough to access both easily.